# Search, Sort and aggregate documents

Tags: couchdb

I have a database with two different document types:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "type": "User",
  "username": "User 1"
}
```

and a second document type with the following structure:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "type": "Asset",
  "name": "Asset one",
  "owner_id": "1"  //id of the user who owns the asset
}
```

We need to display the list of existing assets and the name of the owner (side by side). We were able to achieve this by using views and linked documents. The problem is, now we need to be able to search and sort which is not supported by views.

Is what we're trying to accomplish possible using CouchDB? Can we do this using search indexes?

We're using CouchDB 2.3.1 and we're not able to upgrade (at least for now).

I need to search for `username` and asset `name` and also be able to sort by these fields. We don't need a full featured search. Something like `matches` (case insensitive) is good enough.

The id / owner_id specified in the examples, represent the  document _id. A user will not own more than ~10 assets. The normal scenario will be 2/3 assets.

Comment: Without more detail - e.g. *what* you want to search and sort on - no one can provide a clear answer.  For full text style search etc. have a look at [CouchDB-Lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene).

Comment: The property **id** in your docs above - do you mean that to be the document _id?

Comment: Also, may the number of *assets* owned by a user be very large, say more than a hundred?

Comment: Hi @RamblinRose. I've edited the question to answer your questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do Asset *names* change, or are they immutable?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the complete nature of the asset documents (e.g. lifetime, immutability etc) this may get you moving in a positive direction.  The problem appears that information from both documents is needed to generate a meaningful view, which isn't happening.

Assuming asset names are immutable and the number of assets per user are low, consider decoupling and denormalizing the `owner_id` relationship by keeping a list of assets in the User document.

For example, a User document Where the `assets` property contains a collection of owned asset document information (_id, name):

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "type": "User",
  "username": "User 1",
  "assets": [
    [
      "2",
      "Asset one"
    ],
    [
      "10",
      "Asset ten"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Given this structure, an Asset document is fairly thin

```
{
  "_id": "2", 
  "type": "Asset",
  "name": "Asset one"
}
```

I will assume there is much more information in the Asset documents than presented.

So how to get search and sorted results?  Consider a design doc `_design/user/_view/assets` with the following map function:

```js
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type === "User" && doc.assets) {
    for(var i = 0; i < doc.assets.length; i++) {
      /* emit user name, asset name, value as asset doc id */
      emit(doc.username + '/' + doc.assets[i][1], { _id: doc.assets[i][0] });
      /* emit asset name with leading /, value as User doc _id */
      emit('/' + doc.assets[i][1], { _id: doc._id })
    }
  }
}
```

Let's assume the database only has the one user "User 1" and two Asset documents "Asset one" and "Asset ten".

This query (using cUrl)

```
curl -G <db endpoint>/_design/user/_view/assets
```

yields

```
{
  "total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
    {"id":"1","key":"/Asset one","value":{"_id":"1"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"/Asset ten","value":{"_id":"1"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"User 1/Asset one","value":{"_id":"2"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"User 1/Asset ten","value":{"_id":"10"}}
  ]
}
```

Not very interesting, except notice the rows are returned in ascending order according to its `key`.  To reverse the order simply adding the `descending=true` parameter

```
curl -G <db endpoint>/_design/user/_view/assets?descending=true
```

yields

```
{
  "total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
    {"id":"1","key":"User 1/Asset ten","value":{"_id":"10"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"User 1/Asset one","value":{"_id":"2"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"/Asset ten","value":{"_id":"1"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"/Asset one","value":{"_id":"1"}}
  ]
}
```

Now here's where things get cool, and those cool things are `startkey` and `endkey`.

For the nature of the keys we can query all assets for "User 1" and have the Asset documents returned in ordered fashion according to the asset name, leveraging the slash in the key

```
 curl -G <db endpoint>/_design/user/_view/assets 
 -d "startkey="""User%201/"""" -d "endkey="""User%201/\uFFF0""""
```

<sup>note I'm on Windows, where we have to escape double quotes ;(</sup>

yields

```
{
  "total_rows":4,"offset":2,"rows":[
    {"id":"1","key":"User 1/Asset one","value":{"_id":"2"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"User 1/Asset ten","value":{"_id":"10"}}
  ]
}
```

This is a *prefix search*.  Note the use of the high unicode character **\uFFF0** as a terminator; we're asking for all documents in the view that start with "User 1/".

Likewise to get a sorted list of all Assets

```
curl -G <db endpoint>/_design/user/_view/assets 
-d "startkey="""/"""" -d "endkey="""/\uFFF0""""
```

yields

```
{
  "total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
    {"id":"1","key":"/Asset one","value":{"_id":"1"}},
    {"id":"1","key":"/Asset ten","value":{"_id":"1"}}
  ]
}
```

Since the Asset document _id is emit'ed, use `include_docs` to fetch the Asset document:

```
 curl -G <db endpoint>_design/user/_view/assets -d "include_docs=true"  
 -d "startkey="""User%201/"""" -d "endkey="""User%201/\uFFF0""""
```

yields

```
{
  "total_rows": 4,
  "offset": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "key": "User 1/Asset one",
      "value": {
        "_id": "2"
      },
      "doc": {
        "_id": "2",
        "_rev": "2-f4e78c52b04b77e4b5d2787c21053155",
        "type": "Asset",
        "name": "Asset one"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "key": "User 1/Asset ten",
      "value": {
        "_id": "10"
      },
      "doc": {
        "_id": "10",
        "_rev": "2-30cf9245b2f3e95f22a06cee6789d91d",
        "type": "Asset",
        "name": "Asset 10"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Same goes for Assets where the User _id is emit'ted.

**Caveat**

The major *drawback* here is that deleting an Asset document requires updating the User document; not the end of the world but it would be ultra nice to avoid that dependency.

Given the original 1-1 relationship of asset to user, totally getting rid of the Asset document all together and simply storing all Asset data with the User document might be feasible depending on your usage, and wildly reduces complexity.

I hope the above inspires a solution.  Good luck!